# Fix DOCUMENT_ROOT when fiddling with public tree

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

I have to deal with hosting services that don't allow non-public directories. I can normally use `mod_rewrite` to insert an extra directory level:

```
# /home/foo/public_html/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

…so `http://example.com/test.php` loads `/home/foo/public_html/public/test.php` instead of `/home/foo/public_html/test.php`. But this won't change the value of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` env variable.

Is there a way to change the variable in an `.htaccess` file? My attempts aren't going too far—the value I set with:

```
SetEnv DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/foo/public_html/public
```

… ends up in `REDIRECT_DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Comment: What really you need `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I know what you mean and I can certainly live without it. But I'm curious about this specific tool.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is reserved Apache variable which cannot be overwritten in .htaccess. You can use any other variable name like `DOC_ROOT`

Comment: @anubhava Feel free to post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is actually reserved Apache+PHP variable that cannot be overwritten in `.htaccess` or in Apache config. [`DOCUMENT_ROOT` indicates document root directory of your website](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

You can use any other variable name like `DOC_ROOT` for your case.

Comment: Just a remark: PHP's `$_SERVER` contains a copy of the value provided by Apache but in fact it's writeable as all other keys.

Comment: Yes that's true. Inside PHP code you can overwrite these variables